# No password restrictions shown on register page

Tags: joomla-3.4, login, redirect, registration

I enabled password restrictions on my site. The restrictions work, but the user gets no feedback if his password doesn't meet the requirements - he just gets redirected to the registration form without any error message.

Also, if the registration succeeds, the redirected site is empty

You can try it out [here](http://elab.htu.tugraz.at/index.php/login?view=registration).

Requirements:
Min-Length: 6
Min-Numbers: 1
Min-Special Chars: 1

Comment: Did you manually write the code for this or are you using a plugin?

Comment: @Lodder, I guess he uses the core com_user options for password requirements

Comment: @FFrewin - Learn something new every day. I had no idea these options were available :/

Comment: @FFrewin you guessed right, I'm using the core options. They work - but the user gets no feedback why his password wasn't accepted - like "too short" or "you need at least one number"

Comment: Do you have system messages turned off?

Comment: Do you get a message if the password is incorrect when you try and login on your account?

Comment: @isherwood umm.. I can say that I didn't turn them off on purpose, but I found no clue where i could turn them off or on again. I didn't notice that before, but no, there is also no error message when a login fails. I guess System Messages are turned off, how can I turn them on again?

Comment: Global configuration, under the Server tab if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the default Joomla template or user system has a method of alerting a user when password requirements have been met during registration.

What you can do however is create a jquery script and load it on your registration page that does this for you. Take a peek at [jQuery Password Strength Verification](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/password-strength-verification-with-jquery/)

Install the Flexi Custom Code Module from the JED, create your jQuery script and publish it to the debug position of your template on the registration page. Shouldn't take very long at all to cobble together following the example.